# Creating a function to logout a WordPress user?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a function to logout WordPress users after a period of inactivity. The timed element is working as it should and redirecting users after a set period of time.

The problem is that once the PHP script is loaded (in code sample), I run into the following error: **Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_logout() in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/ion-wp-login-timeout/scripts/timed-logout.php on line 5**

All the reference material I read tells me that wp_logout() should log out the user but instead there are errors. I have tried several methods, including adding an action. I do not want to redirect the user to a login screen.

Sample of code is below. The echo statements are in place purely for testing. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php

    function logout_this_session() {
        //Logout Now
        wp_logout();
        wp_die();
    }

    echo 'This will be the logout script<br/><br/>';

    $last_page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    echo 'You came from: ' . $last_page;

    logout_this_session();

    header( 'Location: ' . $last_page );

?>
```

Comment: Hi there you can simply try https://wordpress.org/plugins/inactive-logout/ this plugin and view source code on how it is done.. Let me know if there are any issues understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution as in code sample below. From the last stage of the process before logging out the user, I have a wpsessionexpired=true value posted back to the page the user was on. The same page is immediately refreshed after the user is logged out. I placed this within the main plugin file.

```
function logoutUser(){
    if ( $_POST["wpsessionexpired"] == 'true' ){ 
        wp_logout();
        header("refresh:0.5;url=".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."");
    }
}
add_action('init', 'logoutUser');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make your function inside functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'redirect_after_logout');
function redirect_after_logout(){
  wp_redirect( 'http://example.com' );
  exit();
}
```

Then  put this in your desire position of your site:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" >Logout</a>
```

Comment: I've implemented this inside my functions.php file and have decided to call this function as `<button class="logbtn" onclick="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>">Logout</button>`, but is not currently executing on button click. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This must use in **init** action.
You can use **wp_logout()** functions that logout current user.
the details of this function in **wp-includes/pluggable.php** file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Log the current user out.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
function wp_logout() {
    wp_destroy_current_session();
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();

    /**
     * Fires after a user is logged-out.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_logout' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Hamed Moodi; [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49196589/4471049)

Create a custom function that logs out users

```
/**
 * Log the current user out.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
function my_custom_user_logout() {
    wp_destroy_current_session();
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();

    /**
     * Fires after a user is logged-out.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_logout' );
}
```

Then create a custom redirect after logout

```
add_action('init', 'mfsl_logout');
function mfsl_logout(){
    if ( $_POST["wpsessionexpired"] == 'true' ){ 
        wp_logout();
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() ); // custom URL to redirect after logot
        exit();
    }
    
    
}
```

When logs out they will be redirected to the home page or to any custom URL

Answer (score 0):

Logout function according user role
 (this is a working code) copy and paste in function.php file

```
    function redirect_after_logout() {

        $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
        $role_name      = $current_user->roles[0];

        if($role_name == 'subscriber'){
            $redirect_url = site_url();
            wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
            exit;
        } 

    }
    add_action( 'wp_logout', 'redirect_after_logout'  );
```

Answer (score 0):

this is also working for

```
      <?php 
if (current_user_can('client') OR current_user_can('salesrep') ){
?>
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" class="btn btn-primary"
style="float: right;" >Logout</a>
<?php }
?>
```

you can set any role as your need. like is this example (client, salesrep)